# Spin Loop vs Cache Miss: which is costlier?

Tags: atomic, cpu-cache, compare-and-swap

For atomic operations on a integers whose size is bigger larger than the size of a pointer, is it better to use a spin loop to implement it or is it better to dynamically allocate the object, and use CAS to update it?

I know that dynamically allocating the object increases the chance for a cache miss, but then using a spin-loop also reduces concurrency. Please which one is costlier, or does it depend on the size of the object? I'm thinking that a spin-loop should be fine for when the object is not more than 3X bigger than the size of a pointer. Am I right to assume this?

*************** edit ****************

What I mean by spin-loop here is a mutual exclusion spin-lock on the object. In the first scenario we use a pessimistic control mechanism where we obtain the lock to read, set or update the object.

In the second scenario, we dynamically allocate the object and make its pointer atomic. A read would just be an atomic load of the pointer and then dereferencing it. A store would be to dynamically allocate the new value, and then perform an atomic store of its pointer. For update operations, we use an optimistic approach of first reading the pointer, calculate the result and dynamically allocate it and then try to update the atomic pointer using CAS.

Using a mutual exclusion spin-lock would reduce concurrency but I'm worried about the cost of a cache-miss if I dynamically allocate the object. In what situations might we choose each approach?

Comment: Using CAS *is* a spin loop -- you spin (repeat the operation) if the CAS fails.  Or perhaps you are asking about a spin lock (which might be implemented with a CAS or simple test-and-set or atomic-swap).  Also, CAS generally cannot be used to update an object larger than a pointer.

Comment: If you're asking about the relative cost of using a spin-lock on a single statically allocated object, vs CAS to update a statically allocated pointer to a dynamically allocated object, this will depend heavily on the amount of contention.  The spin lock will be faster when there's no contention, but will slow down more with more contention.

Comment: Spin locks have their own problems, especially for threaded applications running in a multitasking OS.  You might think "the update only takes a few cycles, so the other thread won't have to spin for long".  But what if your thread gets scheduled out while it holds the spinlock?  Then the other thread will spin for several timeslices, until your thread gets scheduled back in again.  Not only does it make no progress but it wastes CPU time and power in the meantime.

Comment: In most cases you really want a normal mutex instead.  On many modern OSes, it has no extra overhead when not contended, and even if the lock is already held when you try to take it, it will often spin optimistically for a few cycles before yielding the CPU to sleep.  So if updates are pretty fast anyway, the best case is equally good and the worst case is less bad.

Comment: CAS has some difficulties too.  When you swap the old pointer with the new one, how do you know when it is safe to deallocate the old object?  Other threads may have loaded the old pointer in the past and still be using that object.  So you need something like reference counts as well.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. That actually makes a lot of sense.